# p2p publish and play

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, adobe, flash-media-server

Struggling here with p2p. Can someone clarify this for me...everything I'm reading is not consistant including the adobe documentation.

To PUBLISH a p2p you need to:

```
var nc:NetConnection = new NetConnection();
var ns:NetStream = new NetStream(nc, NetStream.DIRECT_CONNECTIONS);
ns.attachCamera(cam);
ns.attachAudio(mic);

groupSpecifier = new GroupSpecifier("fms.mygroup");
groupSpecifier.multicastEnabled = true;
groupSpecifier.postingEnabled = true;
groupSpecifier.serverChannelEnabled = true;

group = new NetGroup(nc,groupSpecifier.groupspecWithAuthorizations());
group.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, onNetStatus);

ns.publish("stream");
```

That should publish it I believe. Is that right?

Then there is VIEWING the live stream:

```
var v2:Video = new Video();
var ns2:NetStream = new NetStream(nc,myPeerID);
ns2.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS,onPublish);
ns2.client = this;
ns2.play(userName);
v2.attachNetStream(ns2);
c.addChild(v2);
```

myPeerID is unique but I cannot see the stream. So here are my questions:

1) Is it possible that I cannot see my own stream for some reason?

2) For the viewing...maybe it is not seeing the stream because I didn't say anything about the groupSpecifier. Although I did attach the groupSpecifier to the nc so wouldn't that be all set because I did that already? I'm just thinking maybe I'm not connected to the same group.

3) I did the configuration multistream html page like it said to do. I then put the manifest.f4m on the server like it said. Do I need to make reference to any of that in my stream name? I saw an article giving a query string that I could use in FMLE. I thought maybe I would need to use that as my stream name?

4) For viewing...in the netStream connection...some people have it to be the peerID as the second argument while others have it be groupSpecifier.groupspecWithAuthorizations(). It would be peerID right since I need to say I want to view that person and it knows which group to connect to because I specified that when I did the GroupSpecifier in the nc.

5) Does the name of the stream in publish....ns.publish("stream") mean anything? Could it be horse or donkey? Why do I have to specify anything if it should know what group to connect to based on the groupSpecifier? Is it because you can connect to a "group" and within that group you can be connected even finer to the "donkey" netstream?

Answer (score 1):

2) you are publishing with `NetStream` over `NetConnection`, not `NetStream` over `NetGroup`, so you don't need `NetGroup` at all when publishing directly to other peer connecting with `NetStream(nc, peerId)`

When you use `NetStream(nc, NetStream.DIRECT_CONNECTIONS)` you don't publish over `NetGroup`, so you need to connect with `NetStream(nc, peerID)`

If you use `NetStream(nc, gs.groupspecWithAuthorizations())` then you play with `NetStream(nc, gs.groupspecWithAuthorizations())`

You need to choose to publish over NetStream@DIRECT_CONNECTIONS or NetStream@NetGroup

4a) argument peerId is for NetStream@DIRECT_CONNECTIONS

4b) argument gs.groupspecWithAuthorizations() is for NetStream@NetGroup

5) yes it does :) you need to publish and play the same string, it's identification of the stream: `ns.publish("StreamName")` and then `ns2.play("StreamName")`

- if you are interested with publishing over NetGroup see [Simple chat with P2P NetGroup / Tom Krcha](http://www.flashrealtime.com/simple-chat-p2p-netgroup-rtmfp/)
- if you want publish directly see [Using peer-to-peer applications / Tom Krcha](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashmediaserver/articles/p2p_apps_cirrus_lccs.html?devcon=f3)
- or just go wild at http://www.flashrealtime.com/